# I can't access to cpanel after modiyfing htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

So, I have a website on neubox hosting, I was trying to change the htaccess to increase the limits to upload files in wordpress, so one of the solutions was to modify the .htaccess file, I did it and after that now I can't even access to the my website. it's completely down, I tried the folllowing:

Through mywebsite.com:port, ipdomain:port, mywebsite.com/cpanel and also filezilla using all the methods above

Is there any other way to access my website?

Comment: So **UNDO** the changes that you made to the `.htaccess` file

Comment: A change to `.htaccess` should not effect FTP access. So either you did something else, or because of what you did to `.htaccess` your host has closed you down. Ask your host!

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to contact support if you cannot access your site at any point. Most likely solution is that the file gets modified back via the command line on the server. The only question is if they allow you access to do that, or if you could just tell them the problem and they would resolve it.

Depends entirely on the host

Comment: This is really just a comment.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I did, but they have not answer yet, so thats why I was trying to see if there is something else I can do

Comment: Well the answer is "It will likely have to be modified back by the command line". Applied to her situation, she may or may not have access to that. I don't see any other "proposed" solutions that could differ from this. I would say that's an answer.